# Is there a way to tell the career banner to not only show jobs in my area?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-deferred, jobs

I would like to see all interesting jobs in the banner and not only the ones in my area.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, no.  But we're working on it.

The best we can do for *most* people is tell them a job is near them.  But for some, like you, there are many places you'd be willing to work or consider if the right opportunity presented itself.  We don't yet know exactly how we'll do it, but it should include some information from your profile (both Stack Overflow and Careers 2.0) which give us more geo-data for targeting purposes.

Example: On your Careers profile you can indicate the places you're willing to relocate to...

[image]

Even with these upgrades to ad serving, most users will still default to geography based on their IP, but it will significantly help a small minority or users.

Comment: Appreciate to see that you are working on it.